# How to force mark folder as up to date with head revision without taking svn update/checkout when we know the files are all already identical?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn

I have a path say `'A'` on subversion repository in which I want to make some changes but do not want to commit the changes inside `'A'` again.

I have following on my system:

- `'A'`s up-to-date working copy on my system is in folder `'X'`

I take following steps:

- Copy `'A'` on subversion repository to `'B'`
- Export `'X'` to another folder on my system `'Y'`

How can I force subversion to mark `'Y'` folder on my system up-to-date with `'B'` on repository without taking any update from `'B'` as it already has identical files with `'B'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second thought - instead of svn copy and export you might just copy locally whole working copy with all svn metadata to a different location and update it occasionally

Comment: Will not do exactly that I want but this gives a solution which I didn't think about. If I copy entire working copy to another folder 'Y'  instead of exporting and then use svn switch 'Y' to 'B' - this will have same effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already copied A with `svn copy` on remote server, svn doesn't really COPY data there, it just create pointers to old data. When updating working copy, to optimize network operations it will just make local copy of old data to new location.
Then just commit main files, not branches. like

```
svn ci trunk
```

leaving branch version uncommited

I've found good article covering new svn functionality

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/reducing_network_traffiic_in_subversion_1-8

Answer (score 1):

If they are SAME repository, SAME version and SAME branch. I guess you could just delete your 'B' and do a full recursion copy (cp -a) from 'A', including hidden folders and meta files.

SVN checkout do more then a download copy, it fetch and compare version and cache latest HEAD.

I could suggest you go for a git solution, using git-svn as a proxy copy and just use git on your working folder.